# How should I organize build instructions for third-party packages?

Tags: python, builds, packages, docker

In my projects I have several third-party Python packages which I need to build from source (because there are no .whl packages published for the versions+platforms I need). Currently these packages are built in the Dockerfiles which create my development containers and deployment containers. This has a few drawbacks:

- the third-party packages are rebuilt too often (even if the package itself has not changed it might be rebuilt, depending on the Docker layer cache). This increases build times.
- if the same package is used in multiple projects, the build instructions are sometimes duplicated (i.e. once in each project). Over time this can cause inconsistency between the builds, if changes are not applied in all places.
- the Dockerfiles become more difficult to maintain: rather than just installing all packages from a single requirements.txt or Pipfile, there are multiple installation steps; and it is not clear afterwards from which source/repository a package was installed.

I already have a company-wide repository for Python packages; so I could build and upload .whl files for the third-party Python packages, and then install them as usual.

Also, the third-party packages change rarely (maybe once every few months); so they don't need to be rebuilt often. OTOH this also means that the builds should be automated as much as possible (because noone here will get much practice in building these packages if this is only done rarely).

And sure, I could try to solve some of the mentioned drawbacks by using Docker features (like including Docker files in each other, using multi-stage builds, etc.).
But I wonder: what is the "usual" solution for reliably building and maintaining my own binary packages of third-party dependencies?

Comment: Is automating the builds worth it? Let's say the third-party package is on v1.2 now. There's nothing that says that the build process for 1.3 or 2.0 will be the same. If any scripts or manual steps change, your automation will also change. And if you're only building a new version of this packages every few months, is the time to build and maintain automation for someone else's project in your own private space worth it? If they are open-source projects, perhaps it's more valuable to contribute improved build scripts to the projects and get community help to make everyone's build easier.

Comment: Author and add [conda forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge) feedstock for the package. Encourage the upstream package author to maintain it.

Comment: *"packages change rarely - [...] so they don't need to be rebuilt often[...]. OTOH this also means that the builds should be automated as much as possible"* - Sorry, but that is a fallacy. It actually means first and foremost you need to document the build steps thoroughly, so a rebuild can be done manually (and can be adapted more easily when the build steps change, as Thomas Owens' scetched above. When you just automate, and then the scripts fails for a new version, someone will have a pretty hard time to fix the automation.

Comment: ... that does not mean you cannot try to automate the process, too, as a bonus, but not *"as much as possible"*, only *"as much as sensible"*.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Good point not to put too much effort into build automation for such packages. Regarding documentation: I like writing/having good docs, but I feel more comfortable writing the build steps in code rather than in prose (and I have most of the build steps already available in the existing Dockerfiles). So maybe I'll just create a repo for those 3rd-party build instructions, with a Dockerfile or shell script for each 3rd-party project; and then we can use that as documentation and for building, and adjust it for future releases.

Comment: @oliver: it depends how readable the build steps in some script are. Ideally, you have both, some script plus some documentation, probably at a slightly higher level of abstraction. Prose can help to understand what you have to do in a few months when your original buld script does not work any more because of a changed build process.